# Using Fullscreen in Yii

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, yii, fullscreen

I am trying to implement full screen for my project using Yii... I downloaded the fullscreen script from https://github.com/martinaglv/jQuery-FullScreen

However when i try to implement it as mentioned in the tutorial it gives a message function fullscreen() not a function. But the same works for simple HTML page.

```
<div id="MyFullScreen">
This is a test
</div>
<div id="fsButton">Click me</div>

$(function(){
    $('#fsButton').click(function(e){
       // Use the plugin
        $('#MyFullScreen').fullScreen();
        e.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

Kindly help. Am clueless as to why it doesn't work...

Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you include the fullscreen javascript file?

Comment: Yes the fullscreen js along with jquery 1.9.0 and jquery-iu has been included...

Comment: Try to include the full-screen js file and use the firebug script option to see if its loaded or not.

Comment: the fullscreen js file is loaded @SudhanshuSaxena

Answer (score 1):

May be some Conflicts.Try to encapsulate

```
jQuery.noConflict();
jQuery(document).ready(function($){ 
  $('#fsButton').click(function(e){
    $('#MyFullScreen').fullScreen();
    e.preventDefault();
  }); 
});
```

Comment: Yes the problem was because of some conflicts. It seems to be conflicting with mprint js... Thanks for your help @Sudhashu

Comment: Your answer was useful as it got me going... But your code did not work in my case...